C# EF Core 8 - Can't solve "The given key 'EmptyProjectionMember' was not present in the dictionary"
I would like to preface by saying that I am very new to EF Core, and have looked at the other few questions about this topic already, and I could not understand how to solve my problem.
I have a model Attempt:
public class Attempt(int Id, string UserId, int score)
{
    public int Id { get; set; } = Id;
    public string UserId { get; set; } = UserId!;
    public int score { get; set; } = score;
}

I am trying to execute this query, which groups all attempts by their UserId, selects the attempt with the highest score per user, then sorts them by score:
IQueryable<Attempt> GetBestAttempts() =>
    db.Attempt
    .GroupBy(a => a.UserId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(attempt => attempt.score).First())
    .OrderByDescending(attempt => attempt.score)
    .ThenBy(attempt => attempt.UserId);

However, when attempting to instantiate this query, I get this error:
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 'The given key 'EmptyProjectionMember' was not present in the dictionary.'

Anyone have a solution for this that does not require instantiating the query? This query is part of many other queries, and I wish to avoid instantiating this huge list to the server if possible.

Try to do not use primary constrctor.

why not? (besides this is just a min reproducible example, my actual model does not even have a c'tor to begin with)

Yes, missed that you have GroupBy. Which EF Core version do you use? This construction should be translatable in EF Core 8.

I'm in ef core 8 (says so in the title)

Well, then they still have translation problems. Try replace Select with .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(attempt => attempt.score).Take(1))

Managed to solve this with a raw query, thanks Microsoft copilot...
IQueryable<Attempt> GetBestAttempts() =>
   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw(db.Attempt, @"
SELECT a.*
FROM ""Attempt"" a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ""UserId"", MAX(""score"") AS ""MaxScore""
    FROM ""Attempt""
    GROUP BY ""UserId""
) maxAttempts ON a.""UserId"" = maxAttempts.""UserId"" AND a.""score"" = maxAttempts.""MaxScore""
WHERE a.""Id"" = (
    SELECT MIN(innerA.""Id"")
    FROM ""Attempt"" innerA
    WHERE innerA.""UserId"" = a.""UserId"" AND innerA.""score"" = a.""score""
)
ORDER BY a.""score"" DESC, a.""UserId"";
");

As much as I hate raw SQL queries, this will do for now.
(I called the extension method directly because I also use Linq2Db in my project and want to avoid name conflicts)

Apparently, EF still can't translate query shapes that EF6 (for .NET Framework) didn't have problems with.
Fortunately, there's a work-around. The first part of the query, GroupBy + Select, can be translated. Since that part does the main job of reducing fetched data in the database, it's not a problem to do the ordering in-memory by adding AsEnumerable:
IEnumerable<Attempt> GetBestAttempts() =>
    db.Attempt
    .GroupBy(a => a.UserId)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(attempt => attempt.score).First())
    .AsEnumerable()
    .OrderByDescending(attempt => attempt.score)
    .ThenBy(attempt => attempt.UserId);

The only thing is, you won't be able to compose an IQueryable that contains GetBestAttempts(). If that is what you want you'll have to remove the ordering. But then, when composing queries, ordering the constituent parts is hardly ever relevant.
For the record, I tried a similar query using .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(attempt => attempt.score).Take(1)). That suffered similar translation errors.

yeah.. I only ever use GetBestAttempts() as part of another query, hell, I concatenate it to a LinqToDB query builder later to use its Rank method to get the rank of a certain attempt DB-side, which I'm not sure if it actually cares about the order of the query it's based on

For now, I managed to make my query work with the raw sql query down below, and I have deadlines approaching, so I will return to this question after said deadlines
